# I get 530 access denied in ftp connection after some upgrade in my internet connection

Tags: ftp, connection, cpanel

I have a ftp connection profile save in ftp site manager, It is still working before I have my internet connection upgraded. But after, i got 530 FTP Access denied and there are some websites that whenever I visit I always get Security Check. When I check the site's cpanel I can't see my ip add being block. Can someone tell me what to do, please.

Answer (score 1):

Who is your hosting company? have you tried to contact them first, Do you or the server have a firewall in place that is prohibiting the connection? Reply with more information or give your hosting company a call.